# American English or English English?

Tags: discussion

I wish to sign up for this website but is the English based on English English or American English? I need American English

Comment: You sir has just won the internet.

Comment: Blimey! Unfortunately, it's English English. Nuff said, yeah?

Comment: We do it all! Now with 50% more *Australian* English!

Comment: We arm wrestle to decide which.

Comment: You can also consider visiting [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/143/shouldnt-there-be-a-necessary-tag-for-the-various-dialects-of-english/145#145

Comment: I wonder if there are people who achieved what this man has. First post and it is moved to meta.

Comment: We cover both American and British English and all varieties of English. Note that we use 'British English' instead of 'English English' (the English primarily spoken in the UK).

Comment: *Glides in on the back of two bald eagles, with an apple pie in one hand and a waving star-spangled banner in the other* **U S A! U S A! U S A!**

Comment: @DanBron Yet another [*americanata*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331156/what-is-the-ame-and-bre-for-americanata) :)

Answer (score 9):

The site name is neither "American English Language and Usage" nor "British English Language and Usage". It is "English Language and Usage".

As long as your questions are related with English (American, British, Australian, New Zealand, Canadian, Indian, etc.) and its usage, they are all welcome unless they are off-topic based on the [guidelines of our help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please don't ask

> 1. Proofreading ("Is this right?", "Are there any mistakes?"), unless the source of concern is clearly specified
> 2. Writing advice (see Writers.SE instead) or critique requests
> 3. "How to improve my English?" (this is not constructive anyway)
> 4. Translation and non-English languages — please see the translation tag info for details
> 5. Naming, including naming programming variables/classes
> 6. Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature
> 7. Jokes that do not rely on the English language

If you are a speaker of other languages learning English, you can consider visiting our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question.